# Is there a bug when defined the return type of a function? As `def xxx() -> str:`, code highlight whill be display error when I use `->`

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

As `def xxx() -> str:`, code highlight whill be display error when I use `->`

[image]

It's not a bug of the theme

If it can be solved by setting rules, can you help me solve it? Or a bug?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: there is no error using type hinting unless your python version is < 3.5

Comment: why don't you post the test code as text also, do you expect me to type it over literally including all your possible typos

Comment: use the TextMate Scope Inspector to determine why `test1` has different colors, in `test_def` type of `test1` is `Any`, in `test_a` it is a `number`, you should use identical code (different function name) in both functions and only add the function return type to one

Comment: Thanks... The problem has been solved, it's a bug of extension, name: "**Python for VSCode**"

Answer (score 1):

You may have **Inlay Type Hints** enabled. Follow the steps below to disable.

File --> Preferences --> Settings, Search for `python inlay hints`, uncheck the two options in the picture.

[image]

Or directly add the following configuration in the **settings.json** file

```json
    "python.analysis.inlayHints.functionReturnTypes": false,
    "python.analysis.inlayHints.variableTypes": false
```

More information can be found [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-july-2022-release/#inlay-type-hints) and [here](https://dev.to/kjaymiller/make-inlay-type-hints-in-python-appeardisappear-njk).

Comment: Thanks but I have both turned off
After troubleshooting,  it was caused by an extension I had installed, and now that plugin has been deprecated, name: "**Python for VSCode**"

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug of vscode.
It was caused by an extension I had installed, and now that plugin has been deprecated, name: "**Python for VSCode**"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).